# ASP.NET chart DataBindCrossTable with horizontal bars

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, charts

I'm using .net 4 charting, and I need to plot a chart that must have several columns grouped together. The solution is to use the DataBindCrossTable function, which perfectly suits my needs; however, the chart needs to be drawed as lines instead of columns. The DataBindCrossTable doesn't seem to work with bar charts, only columns.

Is there a way to rotate the columns horizontally or any other solution ?

Thank you

Comment: By searching documentation, discussion and blogs it seems like you can use only columns. Function Data binds a chart to the table, with one series created per unique value in a given column.

Answer (score 2):

In the code behind file, change the Series.ChartType  value to StackedBar for each series.

C#:

```
foreach (Series data in chtChartControl.Series)
{
    data.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar;
}
```